# Controller is returning blank View in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web, ibm-cloud

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Contact1()
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Session.GetString("login")))
        {
            var pass = new ContactViewModel();
            var username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");              
           Program.readname(HttpContext.Session.GetString("username"));
            var names = HttpContext.Session.GetString("studentnames");

            var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Program.Data>(names);
            if (Program.datecheck(username, DateTime.Today.Date))
            {
              try{
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password) };
                using (var client = Program.CreateHttpClient(handler, user, database3))
                {
                    string check = username + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Date);
                    var readresponse = client.GetStringAsync(check).Result;
                    var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Program.Data>(readresponse);
                  }
                   catch(Exception ee)
                    { ViewBag.m6 = ee.Message; ViewBag.attendance = "Attendace is not take yet";}
                    }  
                    pass.studentattend = obj2.studentattend1;
                }
            }
            else { ViewBag.attendance = "Attendace is not take yet"; }
            pass.studentname = obj1.studentname1;
            pass.studentrollno = obj1.studentrollno1;


            pass.date = DateTime.Today.Date;
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("classselect", 1);
            ViewData["Message"] = "Student Attendance of Class: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("classname1");

            ViewBag.Login = HttpContext.Session.GetString("login");

            ViewBag.name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("name");
            ViewBag.classname1 = HttpContext.Session.GetString("classname1");
            ViewBag.classname2 = HttpContext.Session.GetString("classname2");
            ViewBag.classname3 = HttpContext.Session.GetString("classname3");
            ViewBag.classname4 = HttpContext.Session.GetString("classname4");
            return View("/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml", pass);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Please Login First!!";
            return View("/Views/Home/Login.cshtml");
        }           
    }
```

The above code is runnig well in my local ISS server but when i run this on bluemix then i am getting blank page. I tried to find out the problem and get to the conclusion that if the control does not enter in the if part of that code:

```
 if (Program.datecheck(username, DateTime.Today.Date))
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password) };
            using (var client = Program.CreateHttpClient(handler, user, database3))
            {
                string check = username + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Date);
                var readresponse = client.GetStringAsync(check).Result;
                var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Program.Data>(readresponse);
                pass.studentattend = obj2.studentattend1;
            }
        }
        else { ViewBag.attendance = "Attendace is not take yet"; }
```

then it will run fine.I am unable to find what is wrong in that query.

Comment: There is probably an underlying exception being generated that you are not catching. Wrap the whole thing up in a try/catch block and log that exception. Once you have it please add it to your question. You need the Exception Type, the message, the stack trace, and the same thing for any InnerException that it might contain (and recurse that).

Comment: In general, you return a View either with empty args like - View() or View("Login") when it is a specific view. Or you could try adding a "~" in front of the view's path and see if that works.

Comment: can you check with calling View("~/Views/Home/Login.cshtml") and View("~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml", pass). if you just redirect to your Login action then is it working RedirectToAction( "Login")

Comment: @lgor Can anybody tell me why ` var readresponse = client.GetStringAsync(check).Result ` is not returning anything. Probably it is because of the asyncronous operation and if so then how can i sole this problem

Comment: did you try `var readresponse = await client.GetStringAsync(check);`?